# Backslash inside an alias not being stored as part of its definition

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, zsh, alias

I've got a screen sessions named BedrockServer. I've entered the alias like this:

```
alias stop='screen -R BedrockServer -X stuff "stop $(printf '\r')"'
```

But when I type `alias`, it lists it as

```
alias stop='screen -R BedrockServer -X stuff "stop $(printf r)"'
```

and the alias doesn't work.

---

I've tried messing around with the quotes and using backslashes before the quotes and before the dollar sign, but nothing fixes it.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Using a function instead of an alias would avoid the problems here.

Comment: That said, what's the purpose of the `$(printf '\r')`? It's much more efficient to make your string `$'stop \r'` with no command substitution. (Command substitutions spawn subshells; spawning a subshell is one of the slowest things a shell can do without an `execve()`-family syscall).

Comment: `$'...'` is [ANSI C-like string](https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/quoting#ansi_c_like_strings) syntax. It's not POSIX-mandated, but both bash and zsh provide it.

Comment: The above is all to say that I would write this as `stop() { screen -R BedrockServer -X stuff $'stop \r'; }`. Aliases are a misfeature -- if the shell were redesigned from scratch today with no backwards-compatibility constraints they probably wouldn't exist at all.

Comment: The whole problem can be simplified to either `echo \r` or `xxd <<<\r`, which both show that `\r` simply evaluates to _r_. OTOH, `xxd <<<\\r` would show you that `\\r` is indeed processed as a single backslash, followed by letter `r`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside single quotes all symbols except `'` lose their special meaning. Therefore `$( )` is not interpreted yet. *If* it was interpreted, you could nest quotes. But since it isn't interpreted, you cannot nest quotes.

Your alias is basically

```
'some literal string 'anUnquotedString' another literal string'
```

The unquoted string `\r` is the same as `r`.

Using a function instead of an alias solves the quoting issues easily.

```
stop() {
  screen -R BedrockServer -X stuff "stop $(printf '\r')"
}
```

If you want to stick to an alias, there are many options to get the quoting right, for instance

```
alias stop="screen -R BedrockServer -X stuff \"stop \$(printf '\\r')\""
```

Both commands from above execute `printf` each time you execute `stop`. This is not necessary. In the alias, you can execute it once for the definition (note the missing `\` before `$( )`):

```
alias stop="screen -R BedrockServer -X stuff \"stop $(printf '\r')\""
```

And for the function and/or alias, you even can drop `printf` entirely by using an ANSI C string:

```
stop() {
  screen -R BedrockServer -X stuff $'stop \r'
}
alias stop=$'screen -R BedrockServer -X stuff "stop \r"'
```

Comment: While suggesting improvements, might take out the unnecessary command substitution.